# IDIORM: Unable to extract data from mysql / php (very simple but too complicated for a newbie)

Tags: php, mysql, database, idiorm

I'm trying to extract data from column 'field_data' in table tk_custom_data WHERE:

1. 'product_id' in table 'tk_custom_data' matches 'id' in other table called 'tk_product'
   and
2. 'field_id' in table 'tk_custom_data' is equal to "21"

Result should be extracted when using `$main_result`

But this is simply too complicated for me, I'm still a total newbie. Please help :( Using IDIORM ORM

```
$product_id = ORM::for_table($config['db']['pre'].'product')->find_one($_GET['id']);
$item_id = $product_id['id'];
$value = '21'; 

$result = ORM::for_table($config['db']['pre'].'custom_data')
    ->where('product_id',$item_id)
    ->where('field_id',$value)
    ->find_one();   

foreach ($result as $info) { 
    $main_result = $info['field_data']; 
}
```

Comment: which ORM are you using?

Comment: ADyson thanks for answer. I really don't know cause I'm using a bought Classified Ad CMS. How to check this? If it help: I bought this script: codecanyon.net/item/quickad-classified-ads-php-script/19960675

Comment: There's no source code or any mention of the ORM on that page as far as I can see, so it's hard to tell. Did they not provide any documentation with your purchase? If I had to guess I'd say it could be based on a well-known ORM provided by a 3rd party rather than written directly by these people - there are plenty of open-source ones around. People don't tend to write their own version of that kind of tool when they are really selling something else. Perhaps the source code class names or comments in the files for the ORM part give some clues?

Comment: I found something called IDIORM in file "sql_builder.php". http://github.com/j4mie/idiorm/. Maybe this is it?

Comment: Well the code sample on the home page you've linked to looks pretty similar in style to what you've shown us above, so I'd say yes it's probably the same thing. So you'd need to study the documentation to work out how you're supposed to structure the query you want to write. (I'm assuming you'd know how to write this query if it was in raw SQL?)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Raw SQL is not difficult for me. OK that's a useful tip. I'd study the documentation and try to figure it out :) Thanks ADyson!